# Python: How to use a tuple of tuples as a lookup

Tags: python, list, tuples

Say I have a tuple of tuples like:

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ('AB', 'APPLE BANANNA'),   
    ('O', 'ORANGE'),    
    ('W', 'WATERMELLON'),    
    ('SB', 'STRAWBERRY BANANNA'),  
    ('CM', 'CHERRY MELLON'),    
)
```

How can I use that as a lookup and loop through a list like:

```
fruit_list = ['AB','SB','CM']
```

To make it:

```
['APPLE BANANNA','STRAWBERRY BANANNA','CHERRY MELLON']
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
    fruit_list_final = []

    for fruit in fruit_list:
        fruit_list_final.append( MY_CHOICES[fruit] )

    print fruit_list_final
```

But I'm getting an error: ***TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not unicode***

Comment: just type cast to `dict(MY_CHOICES)`

Comment: Your spellings are wrong: banana and melon

Answer (score 2):

Convert it into a dict.

Example:

```
MY_CHOICES_DICT = dict(MY_CHOICES)
result = [MY_CHOICES_DICT[fruit] for fruit in fruit_list]
print(result)
```

Result is:

```
['APPLE BANANNA', 'STRAWBERRY BANANNA', 'CHERRY MELLON']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
result = [
    next(name for code, name in MY_CHOICES if code == item)
    for item in fruit_list
]
```

This does not build an intermediary dictionary, but iterates the array for every fruit. If the list is small, it might yield better performance. If the list is long, it will be much worse for sure.

Note that a missing fruit will cause a `StopIteration` exception to be raised.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
MY_CHOICES = (
    ('AB', 'APPLE BANANA'),   
    ('O', 'ORANGE'),    
    ('W', 'WATERMELON'),    
    ('SB', 'STRAWBERRY BANANA'),  
    ('CM', 'CHERRY MELON'),    
)

print(next(value for key, value in MY_CHOICES
           if key == 'W'))
```

Will print:

```
WATERMELON
```